# Passing values between thread.timer runs

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm scratching my head here, not sure if this is the right way to approach it but as of right now I can't think of another way(open to suggestions). So I am running the BACpypes library, which requires you to create a device, application then call the `run()` which initiates the the device on the network.

What I am trying to do is send a `write_property` command to the device every couple of minutes but the problem is I can only do so after i call the `run()` method(which initializes and hosts the device), which as soon as I do, nothing beyond that method gets called until I stop the program completely because it's a single threaded application

So I thought I'd create a method called `Update` which will run every 30 seconds and try and write to the device using `thread.Timer`(since it then runs on a seperate thread). The issue I'm having is that the `Update` method I use to write to the device can't be executed until I run the `run()` command, but I have to execute my method before the run() command otherwise it will never execute. Basically what I want to know is can I send a bool to my Update method that will prevent it from running the `write_property` the first time so that it can wait till `run()` has been executed, then every time after that it can try to write to it?  Perhaps just add a try/catch and skip ?

example of what the code looks like: (this is my main try block)

```
isFirstRun = False
try:
    test_device = LocalDeviceObject(...)
    this_application = Application(test_device, args.ini.address)

    Update(None,this_application, isFirstRun)

    run()
```

Update method:

```
def Update(client, app, isFirstRun):
    threading.Timer(30.0, Update, [client,app, isFirstRun]).start()
    if the run() method hasnt been called yet
        skip
    else if it has
        execute rest of code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `Update` directly, why not call `threading.Timer(...)` in your main thread as well? That way `Update` won't be run initially until after 30 seconds have passed which appears to be the same as what you are doing with a the booleans, but a lot less clunky.